# Roots of a polynomials by observation.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, roots, quadratics

Let $f(x)=\dfrac{3}{x-2}+\dfrac{4}{x-3}+\dfrac{5}{x-4}$, then $f(x)=0$ has roots in the intervals?

I managed to do this by concepts of Location of roots (Quadratic Equation).

But it takes a lot of time also time limit is only 2 min any way to do this in short period of time. Please help.

Comment: the question is phrased in a weird way to me, Is this a multiple choice question?

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh yes

Comment: The choices might give us a short cut sometimes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two roots only! On $(2,3)$ and on $(3,4)$.

Because our expression is decreasing on all interval from domain and easy to see,

what happens around $2$, around $3$ and around $4$.

Indeed, $f(x)=0$ is equivalent to $ax^2+bx+c=0$, where $a\neq0$.

Thus, this equation has two real roots maximum.

But $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow2^+}f(x)=+\infty$, $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow3^-}f(x)=-\infty$ and $f$ is a decreasing continuous function on $(2,3)$.

Thus, our equation has an unique root on $(2,3)$.

By the same way we'll get that our equation has an unique root on $(3,4)$ and we are done!

Answer (score 1):

HINT: factorizing the given equation $$f(x)=0$$ we get
$$\frac{2 (2 x-7) (3 x-7)}{(x-4) (x-3) (x-2)}=0$$